# Only Reals Rules

Tags: replacement, conditional, rule, assignment

I have a huge array of rules with many variables, such as

```
{{z[1] -> 0, z[2] -> 0, z[3] -> 0, z[4] -> 0, z[5] -> 0, z[6] -> 0, 
 z[7] -> 0, z[8] -> 0, z[9] -> -(1/2) I z[21], 
 z[10] -> -(1/2) Sqrt[3] z[21], z[11] -> 0, z[12] -> I z[21], 
 z[13] -> 0, z[14] -> 0, z[15] -> z[21]/2, z[16] -> 0, z[17] -> 0, 
 z[18] -> -(z[21]/2), z[19] -> I Sqrt[3] z[21], z[20] -> 0},{z[1] -> 0, z[2] -> 0, z[3] -> 0, z[4] -> 0, z[5] -> 0, z[6] -> 0, 
 z[7] -> 0, z[8] -> -(z[21]/2), z[9] -> (I z[21])/Sqrt[6], z[10] -> 0,
  z[11] -> 0, z[12] -> 0, z[13] -> -z[21], z[14] -> 0, 
 z[15] -> -(z[21]/2), z[16] -> 0, z[17] -> 0, z[18] -> 0, z[19] -> 0, 
 z[20] -> -2 I Sqrt[2/3] z[21]},{z[1] -> 0, z[2] -> 0, z[3] -> 0, z[4] -> 0, z[5] -> 0, z[6] -> 0, 
 z[7] -> 0, z[8] -> -(z[13]/2), z[9] -> z[13]/2, z[10] -> 0, 
 z[11] -> -2 z[13], z[12] -> 0, z[14] -> 0, z[15] -> 0, z[16] -> 0, 
 z[17] -> 0, z[18] -> 0, z[19] -> 0, z[20] -> 0, z[21] -> 0}}
```

These are the solutions to a huge system of equations. There are many more solutions, I just picked a few as an example. All the variables z[j] are Reals, sometimes they are independent variables, some other times they are dependent from the other.

When there are solutions like z[12]-> I z[21], I would like to put z[21] to 0 and consequently, z[12] to 0 (updating the rule), and whenever z[21] appears in one rule inside the same solution I would like to make it vanish. In order to remove all the imaginary solutions.

How can I do that? (If I ask to solve the system only on the Reals, it takes more time than the age of the Universe)

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that the rules observe some consistency (such as they would if derived by `Solve`):

```
Flatten[
 MapThread[
  ReplaceAll,
  {rules, Solve[#1 \[Element] Reals] & /@ Values@rules}
  ],
 1]

(*
{{z[1] -> 0, z[2] -> 0, z[3] -> 0, z[4] -> 0, z[5] -> 0, z[6] -> 0, 
  z[7] -> 0, z[8] -> 0, z[9] -> 0, z[10] -> 0, z[11] -> 0, z[12] -> 0,
   z[13] -> 0, z[14] -> 0, z[15] -> 0, z[16] -> 0, z[17] -> 0, 
  z[18] -> 0, z[19] -> 0, z[20] -> 0},

 {z[1] -> 0, z[2] -> 0, z[3] -> 0, z[4] -> 0, z[5] -> 0, z[6] -> 0, 
  z[7] -> 0, z[8] -> 0, z[9] -> 0, z[10] -> 0, z[11] -> 0, z[12] -> 0,
   z[13] -> 0, z[14] -> 0, z[15] -> 0, z[16] -> 0, z[17] -> 0, 
  z[18] -> 0, z[19] -> 0, z[20] -> 0},

 {z[1] -> 0, z[2] -> 0, z[3] -> 0, z[4] -> 0, z[5] -> 0, z[6] -> 0, 
  z[7] -> 0, z[8] -> -(z[13]/2), z[9] -> z[13]/2, z[10] -> 0, 
  z[11] -> -2 z[13], z[12] -> 0, z[14] -> 0, z[15] -> 0, z[16] -> 0, 
  z[17] -> 0, z[18] -> 0, z[19] -> 0, z[20] -> 0, z[21] -> 0}}
*)
```

The first two solution sets have `z[21]` replaced by `0` but the third is unchanged, since the only variable in the right-hand sides, `z[13]`, is multiplied only by real coefficients.

Note: `Solve` complains about the third set, because there's nothing to do: All (real) values of `z[13]` are ok.

Comment: If the right-hand sides are complicated and have complicated solutions, a more sophisticated processing of `Reduce[#1 \[Element] Reals]` than a simple `Solve` may be needed.  However, `Solve` works on the given examples.

Answer (score 1):

You have a list of list of rules. To make it simple, I first assume that you have only one list of rule. We can then, in a first step, set all complex terms to zero. This gives new rules, however, this new rules may be self referential. E.g. {a1->0,a2->3 a1}, then this should give {a1->0,a2->0}. Therefore, the new rules itself must be applied to the right sides of the new rules. Assuming we have one list of rules named "rules" this can be achieved by:

```
rules = rules /. Complex[_, _] -> 0 ;
(rules[[All, 2]] = rules[[All, 2]] //. rules)
```

But you have not one list of rules but a list of lists of rules. To handle this, we change the code above into a function that we apply onto the different lists:

```
(tmp = # /. Complex[_, _] -> 0 ;
   tmp[[All, 2]] = tmp[[All, 2]] //. tmp; tmp) & /@ list-of-list-of-rules
```

Answer (score 0):

You can replace `z[21]` in your rules with zero with a `Rule`. Just do:

```
rules /. z[21] -> 0
```

This leads to the silly `0->0` in your third set, but that's harmless.

Answer (score 0):

```
Clear["Global`*"]

clean[vec_?VectorQ] := Module[{zeroes = Cases[vec,
       (var_ -> x_?(! FreeQ[#, Complex] &)) :> 
        Thread[Variables[x] -> 0],
       Infinity] // Flatten // Union},
  vec /. zeroes]

rules = {{z[1] -> 0, z[2] -> 0, z[3] -> 0, z[4] -> 0, z[5] -> 0, 
    z[6] -> 0, z[7] -> 0, z[8] -> 0, z[9] -> -(1/2) I z[21], 
    z[10] -> -(1/2) Sqrt[3] z[21], z[11] -> 0, z[12] -> I z[21], 
    z[13] -> 0, z[14] -> 0, z[15] -> z[21]/2, z[16] -> 0, z[17] -> 0, 
    z[18] -> -(z[21]/2), z[19] -> I Sqrt[3] z[21], 
    z[20] -> 0}, {z[1] -> 0, z[2] -> 0, z[3] -> 0, z[4] -> 0, 
    z[5] -> 0, z[6] -> 0, z[7] -> 0, z[8] -> -(z[21]/2), 
    z[9] -> (I z[21])/Sqrt[6], z[10] -> 0, z[11] -> 0, z[12] -> 0, 
    z[13] -> -z[21], z[14] -> 0, z[15] -> -(z[21]/2), z[16] -> 0, 
    z[17] -> 0, z[18] -> 0, z[19] -> 0, 
    z[20] -> -2 I Sqrt[2/3] z[21]}, {z[1] -> 0, z[2] -> 0, z[3] -> 0, 
    z[4] -> 0, z[5] -> 0, z[6] -> 0, z[7] -> 0, z[8] -> -(z[13]/2), 
    z[9] -> z[13]/2, z[10] -> 0, z[11] -> -2 z[13], z[12] -> 0, 
    z[14] -> 0, z[15] -> 0, z[16] -> 0, z[17] -> 0, z[18] -> 0, 
    z[19] -> 0, z[20] -> 0, z[21] -> 0}};

clean /@ rules

(* {{z[1] -> 0, z[2] -> 0, z[3] -> 0, z[4] -> 0, z[5] -> 0, z[6] -> 0, 
  z[7] -> 0, z[8] -> 0, z[9] -> 0, z[10] -> 0, z[11] -> 0, z[12] -> 0,
   z[13] -> 0, z[14] -> 0, z[15] -> 0, z[16] -> 0, z[17] -> 0, 
  z[18] -> 0, z[19] -> 0, z[20] -> 0}, {z[1] -> 0, z[2] -> 0, 
  z[3] -> 0, z[4] -> 0, z[5] -> 0, z[6] -> 0, z[7] -> 0, z[8] -> 0, 
  z[9] -> 0, z[10] -> 0, z[11] -> 0, z[12] -> 0, z[13] -> 0, 
  z[14] -> 0, z[15] -> 0, z[16] -> 0, z[17] -> 0, z[18] -> 0, 
  z[19] -> 0, z[20] -> 0}, {z[1] -> 0, z[2] -> 0, z[3] -> 0, 
  z[4] -> 0, z[5] -> 0, z[6] -> 0, z[7] -> 0, z[8] -> -(z[13]/2), 
  z[9] -> z[13]/2, z[10] -> 0, z[11] -> -2 z[13], z[12] -> 0, 
  z[14] -> 0, z[15] -> 0, z[16] -> 0, z[17] -> 0, z[18] -> 0, 
  z[19] -> 0, z[20] -> 0, z[21] -> 0}} *)
```